# Django not able to fetch model.objects data inside method of view class

Tags: django, object, model, attributes

I am not able to fetch data using  model.objects from method inside view.py class

Mean a while I am able to fetch data from out side of the method in the same class attached screenshot

[(Objects call Out side of Method)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYpkQ.png)

[(Objects call inside of Method)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIfGO.png)

Comment: Seeing the options on VSCode doesn't conclude that you can access it there. Do not trust the text editors, and rely on your code's output.

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.